# I am trying to make a login for my website but is not working

Tags: php, html, sql

This is the php of the login:

```
 <?php

// Get user input values
$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

// Protect againts sql injection
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

//connect to the database and selsct database
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "//im hiding the password");
mysql_select_db("test");

//Query the database for user
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username . "' && password = '" . $password . "'") or die("Failed to query database " . mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if ($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password) {
    echo "Login Successful Welcome: " . $row['username'];
} else {
    echo "Invalid Username or Password";
}
```

This is the html:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Simple Login</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 style="text-align:center;">Simple Login</h1>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <form style="text-align:center;" action="process.php" method="post">
      Username:
      <input type="text" name="user" />
      <br />Password:
      <input type="password" name="pass" />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
  </div>
  </form>
</body>
<html>
```

Could someone tell me why the php won't check the database if the username and password is correct. Oh and when you put nothing in the username and password boxes it logs you in!

Comment: your code is redundant. you're already checking if user/pass match in the query itself, so there is literally zero point in doing it in php as well. the query will return either rows that already match those values, or not results at all. and storing passwords as plaintext in your db is a massive security vulnerability and just asking for trouble.

Comment: @RamRaider: pointless. `&&` and `and` are functionally identical.

Comment: noted.. and removed

Comment: Sidenote: Use `mysqli_` instead. http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should

Comment: nevermind I solved it there was nothing wrong with the code just no users

Comment: I just forget that I had no users because a little while ago I wiped the table so that I could start freash!!! Thanks for everthing anyway!

Comment: Consider looking into MySQLi and prepared statements.

Comment: also consider not storing the passwords as plain text in the db. You're comparing 1 for 1 with no salt, no sha256, nothing. Also check if $row has results before trying to compare against them. and you can join statements like `$password = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($password));`

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
//connect to the database and selsct database
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "//im hiding the password");
```

`mysql_real_escape_string()` **REQUIRES** an active connection to the DB, but you don't do that connection until AFTER. Therefore `m_r_e_s()` will return a boolean FALSE for failure, which you then blindly use in your query. Boolean false in a string context is a zero-length string, so your query will literally become

```
SELECT ... WHERE username='' && password=''
```

And note that `mysql_*()` functions are obsolete and now removed from PHP. You should **NOT** be using them, anywhere, for any reason.

Comment: Also, when `mysql_fetch_array` is called, it returns `false`, so `$row['username'] == $username` is the same as `false == false` which is the same as `true`. Ditto with the password comparison, so that's nice.